# path.resolve(__dirname, 'tools/unzip.exe') crashing with no message on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

I'm writting an application with nwjs, and using [nwjs-updater](https://github.com/Aufree/nwjs-updater) as update system.

Unfortunatly, I've got this issue while trying to use unzip by C. Spieler (docs: https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/unzip.1.asp) on Windows 10.

When I try to invoke the `__dirname` var, the application just crashes.
Here is the code where it fails:

```
// Code imported from https://github.com/Aufree/nwjs-updater/blob/master/basic/updater.js
// Only added console logs for debugging the issue.

var path = require('path');

//(...)
//line 253:
win: function(filename, cb, manifest, temporaryDirectory){
  var destinationDirectory = getZipDestinationDirectory(filename, temporaryDirectory),
      unzip = function(){
        exec( '"' + path.resolve(__dirname, 'tools/unzip.exe') + '" -u -o "' +
            filename + '" -d "' + destinationDirectory + '" > NUL', function(err){
          if(err){
            return cb(err);
          }

          cb(null, path.join(destinationDirectory, getExecPathRelativeToPackage(manifest)));
        });
      };

  console.log(destinationDirectory);                            // Works fine   
  console.log(__dirname);                                       // Never gets to print
  console.log(path.resolve(__dirname, 'tools/unzip.exe'));      // Never gets to this line
  fs.exists(destinationDirectory, function(exists){
    if(exists) {
      del(destinationDirectory, {force: true}, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          cb(err);
        }
        else {
          unzip();
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      unzip();
    }
  });

}
//(...)
```

Here how I start the "updater" variable:

```
var pkg = require(link_to_package.json);
var upd = new updater(pkg);
```

Any idea on where might be the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the EXACT error (word for word) that you get in the console?  And, is `exec` defined somewhere?  Why do you think the fault is with `__dirname`?

Comment: That was the issue, as I was not getting any error in the console.

Comment: The fault is with `__dirname` as it fails on the line where I just do `console.log(__dirname);`

Comment: Did you read my answer below.  If you're using node-webkit as your question is tagged, I think that answer explains it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this problem report](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/264), it appears that `__dirname` does not work in node-webkit because it does not properly define all module-level variables.

Suggested work-arounds are to use [`process.cwd()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_cwd).

Comment: Eventually I just traded the entire zip system. But yes, this helped. Thanks.